# Non-Convex Loss Function

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, gradient-descent

I am trying to understand gradient descent algorithm by plotting the error vs value of parameters in the function. What would be an example of a simple function of the form **y = f(x)** with just just one input variable x and two parameters w1 and w2 such that it has a non-convex loss function ? Is y = w1.tanh(w2.x) an example ? What i am trying to achieve is this :
[image]

How does one know if the function has a non-convex loss function without plotting the graph ?

Answer (score 2):

In iterative optimization algorithms such as gradient descent or Gauss-Newton, what matters is whether the function is locally convex. This is correct (on a convex set) if and only if the Hessian matrix (Jacobian of gradient) is positive semi-definite. As for a non-convex function of one variable (see my Edit below), a perfect example is the function you provide. This is because its second derivative, *i.e* Hessian (which is of size `1*1` here) can be computed as follows:

```
first_deriv=d(w1*tanh(w2*x))/dx= w1*w2 * sech^2(w2*x)
second_deriv=d(first_deriv)/dx=some_const*sech^2(w2*x)*tanh(w2*x)
```

The `sech^2` part is always positive, so the sign of `second_deriv` depends on the sign of `tanh`, which can vary depending on the values you supply as `x` and `w2`. Therefore, we can say that it is not convex everywhere.

**Edit**: It wasn't clear to me what you meant by one input variable and two parameters, so I assumed that w1 and w2 were fixed beforehand, and computed the derivative w.r.t `x`. But I think that if you want to optimize w1 and w2 (as I suppose it makes more sense if your function is from a toy neural net), then you can compute the `2*2` Hessian in a similar way.

Comment: what branch of mathematics deals with the above mentioned concepts ?

Comment: I'd say mainly numerical optimization.

Answer (score 0):

The same way as in high-school algebra: the second derivative tells you the direction of flex.  If that's negative in all orientations, then the function is convex.